# Extrating Product id which is not present in Customer_Order Table

Tags: mysql, sql

my query `select p.idProduct from customer_order c, product p where idProduct not in (select c.product_id from customer_order)`

table 1 product

```
1   cooker  500
2   Frying Pane 600
3   Spoon   110
```

table 2 customerOrder

```
Name    product id
Sohaib      1   
Sohaib      2   
Ammar       2   
Max         2
```

want to get item not in Customer order table which is product  id

After Executing Query Mentioned Above i get

```
Product id
    2
    3
    1
    3
    1
    3
    1
    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `not in` or `not exists`:

```
select p.*
from products p
where not exists (select 1
                  from customerOrder co
                  where co.productid = p.id
                 );
```